# CoreData wont save reference object

Tags: ios, core-data, reference

I'm using core data to store the data in my iOS application. There are two entities, from which one has a to-many association to the other (e.g. 1 course -> many students, 1 student -> many grades) and the inverse.

Whenever I create a new instance of a student (or grade) and pass the course (or student) (NSManagedObject), this reference can't be saved and becomes `null`. No exception, all other values of the object are saved, but the reference to the course is `null`.

What I'm doing:

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Student" inManagedObjectContext:context];
Student *newStudent = (Student *)[[NSManagedObject alloc]initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:context];


[newStudent setLastname:_lastname.text];
[newStudent setFirstname:_firstname.text];
[newStudent setNote:_note.text];

NSNumber *tmp = [NSNumber numberWithInt:(int)[[(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate] staticDataObject]increaseGlobalSchuelerID]];
[newStudent setId:tmp];


[newStudent setCourse:(Course *)_detailItem];
[newStudent setDesktopID:[NSNumber numberWithInt:-1]];


NSError *error = nil;
if (![context save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}
```

The _detailItem is a NSManagedObject of the entity `course`. Do you guys have any idea, why that's not working?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're sure `_detailItem` is a valid reference? Can you log the student and course (`_detailItem`) before saving?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to build the inverse relationship at the same time， which means add newstudent into _detailItem. I solved a similar problem yesterday in this way, but really don't know why.